# Wondering how to delete the files when it's name increments?

Tags: macos, shell

I have a file in the dir as

```
file3.proto
file2.proto
file1.proto
```

I want to delete the file1 and file2, the highest number is the latest file that I don't want to delete. How can I achieve this in the shell script?

This below thing does the job but I want to be more dynamic. I don't want to change the shell script every time if the number increments, example if the file is 4 then I need to change 1..3.

```
ls | grep '.proto' | rm file{1..2}.proto
```

Comment: Wouldn't an `rm file*.proto` be enough? Or is that too "globby"? :)

Comment: no, I want the highest number file to be there. your command will delete all the files. I don't want that.

Comment: Have you considered an `ls` with the "human" option for sorting as you wish, piped to a `tail -1` to get the highest number, followed by a `mv`?  That would let you use your `rm` above, and the final step would be to rename the surviving file.

Comment: Will the file with the highest number ever sort before one with a lower number? For example, will there ever be `file9.proto` and `file10.proto`, where `file10` sorts before `file9`, or would the number be zero-padded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ls *.proto | head -n -1 | xargs rm
```

which with these files

```
file1.proto
file2.proto
file3.proto
```

executes the command

```
rm file1.proto file2.proto
```

*UPDATE*: Be warned that `ls` command outputs files in *alphabetical* order, which is not *numerical* order... I mean, if you have also a `file25.proto`, you'll get this output from `ls`:

```
file1.proto
file25.proto
file2.proto
file3.proto
```

So it should be better (if possible) to rename files like `file001.proto`, depending on the maximum possible number of files present in the folder. This is a common issue with file names ordering...

Comment: Isn't this the opposite of what the question asks, deleting instead of retaining that file?

Comment: This doesn't work: `I get head: illegal line count -- -1`

Comment: Oh, I see it now, `-1`. Why would `ls` show the files in reverse alphabetical order?

Comment: @danglingpointer: Of course I assume you have some '.proto' file in the current directory...

Comment: Not every version of `head` supports negative counts for `-n`.

Comment: There are a few other issues. `grep '.proto'` matches `.proto`, `xproto`, `yproto`... and you don't need grep at all: `ls *.proto` – but [you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) in the first place.

Comment: @MarcoS its *.proto files will exist always in that dir. I just want the highest number only rest I want to delete it.

Comment: @BenjaminW.: you're right, just corrected my answer... :-)

Comment: @danglingpointer: that command deletes all the files with extention .proto, but the last one (in the order used by ls, which is the alphabetic order).

Comment: I got it, I can sort in descending order keep the first element from head and remove rest.

Comment: But default `ls` output is sorting in ascending order and your command would delete all but the oldest one.

Comment: ls *.proto prints, in this order:
file1.proto
file2.proto
file3.proto
So my command removes all but the last file (in this case file3.proto)